# How can I get a specific data from current user using Firebase in Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to get the current user information (name, e-mail, address, etc) using Firebase. How can I do this?

Comment: There's a section [Get the currently signed-in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) in the Firebase documentation that covers this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this to get user id and name

```
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if (firebaseUser != null) {
                    String userId = firebaseUser.getUid();
                    String userEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();

                    textviewUserID.setText(userId);
                    textviewUserEMail.setText(userEmail);
                } 
            }
        };
```

for other details check:--

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/UserInfo

Comment: Actually I'd like to retrieve a specific data from current user to show on TextView. How can I solve that?

Comment: you can use setText property

Answer (score 1):

You can get the instance of the Firebase current user by

```
public static FirebaseUser getFirebaseUser()
    {
    return getFirebaseAuth().getCurrentUser();
    }

public static FirebaseAuth getFirebaseAuth()
    {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }
```

and you can retrieve the details of the users by

```
getFirebaseUser().getDisplayName(), getFirebaseUser().getEmail()
```

Comment: Actually I'd like to retrieve a specific data from current user to show on TextView. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the currentUser property of the signed in user (if no user is signed in then currentUser is null) :

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

if (user != null) {
 name = user.displayName;
 email = user.email;
 photoUrl = user.photoURL;
 emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
 uid = user.uid;
}
```

[firebase currentUser documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Actually I'd like to retrieve a specific data from current user to show on TextView. How can I solve that?

Comment: Use the `setText()` function of your TextView object with the data you need in parameter : `myTextView.setText(user.email);`